# stop execution of php script in eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse

I am having a strange problem. I run a php script that saves data into mysql database. I closed the localhost tab, but the script is still running. I know that because I can count the number of entries in the table and they are incrementing.

So how does one stop a php script? I am using eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can kill the process or stop apache.

Depending on what you have.

Comment: kill process- you mean with command line? or is there a way to do it in eclipse.

Comment: if you are on linux, your php script is going to have a pid. You can use the command kill to stop it. Or if you are on windows, to stop a php script you simply stop apache.